# Camera plugin JQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

http://jsfiddle.net/Rs8F5/

I tested it on IE7 and the error pops [image: Error alert on Ie7]

I thought it might be cause of missing }(jquery) but it is not the case. I couldn't figure it.

Any insight or help would be appreciated. thank you

**EDIT**

Thank you for your help. A few more questions:
1) How to make the image smaller than the slider container so that the text would be on right? the caption is at the bottom - still figuring how to make it move to right in full column.

2) There is a problem with image - images are supposed to slide from right then suddenly the last image would have different transition. I also couldn't figure it out.

Any insight or help on these will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 91:

`onStartTransition: function() {},`

remove the comma.

I think this should fix it.

Comment: thank you so much. Could you also take a look at my questions if you have spare time? thank you